# Statistical learning - How to determine the irreducible error?

Tags: variance, error, bias

I'm reading *Introduction to Statistical Learning*, currently Chapter 2 about the Bias-Variance trade-off.

In all examples the irreducible error is 1, i.e. $Var(\epsilon) = 1$. I read in [Why is the variance of the error term always 1 in examples of the bias-variance tradeoff?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228896/why-is-the-variance-of-the-error-term-a-k-a-the-irreducible-error-always-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) that this is likely for pedagogical reasons.

My question is, how would you actually go about to find the irreducible error? Is this even possible?

Comment: You don't, it's a conceptual tool.

Comment: well, it could be defined as the error of the Bayes classifier. I'm not sure but I think there must be ways to estimate it.